# get facebook extended permission for uploading photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

In my facebook application, when the users first starts using it,the app request very basic permission. At a later stage, I need to request extended permission to allow the app to upload photos, I'm googling when falling only on the legacy part:

```
 FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("photo_upload",permissionHandler);
```

Does someone has any idea how to get permission for uploading photos using the new sdk??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain extended permission from the user, there are two ways to ask the permission from the user. In either way, the finality is to get the permission from the user:

1. Opens a popup and ask the user the extended permission

FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
      // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
  } else {
    // User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.
  }
}, {scope:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});

1. Open a new window and ask the user the permission

   window.location="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=&next=https://apps.facebook.com//&type=user_agent&perms=user_photos,publish_stream,friends_photos&fbconnect=1";

You also need to know which permission you want from the user. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) is a list of permission that you can ask from a facebook user

Answer (score 7):

There is no `photo_upload` permission. But, you can upload photos using the `publish_stream` permission instead. And you can see the user's photos using the `user_photos` permission.