# Facebook published photos do not appear on users page (Received 400:Bad request error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

We have a kiosk based asp.net web application based at tourist attractions that allows visitors to post photos to Facebook taken at the attraction. We popup a web page with the Facebook login page.
In the last few weeks, we have noticed that the photos are not showing up on the users page (timeline or photos).  The posting process (upload.PostFile) returned a 400: Bad Request message.
Here are the parameters being used:

```
filename:   \\file01\Photo\136-H.jpg
fileFieldName:  file
fileContentType:    image/jpeg
requestUri.AbsolutePath:    /me/photos
requestUri.Host:    graph.facebook.com
uri constructor String: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos
FacebookUploadPhotoMessage: Check out this photo from our visit to the XX!
FacebookUploadPhotoMessageParamKey: Upload Photo Message
FacebookPhotoMessageFormName:   message
FacebookAccessTokenFormName:    access_token
FacebookGraphAPIBaseURI:    https://graph.facebook.com/
```

At this point, we are not even sure where to look for the issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this Q and its A? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802197/get-facebook-extended-permission-for-uploading-photos

Comment: I looked at it, but it does appear to be the same issue.  After digging further into our logs I found more info and I edited the content of the above question.